# Load Balance Electric Main Panel

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Circuit breakers have to be attached to both sides of the electric panel in such a way that it balances the load. I would like to know if:

1. I should ensure left circuit breakers Amp is almost same as right panel breakers.
2. Should I balance based on usage? e.g., refrigerators are always working but ACs do not work in winters.
3. Do 2 pole breakers have to be evenly distributed as well?

Any ideas on the right way to arrange the breakers?

Comment: *"circuit breakers have to be attached to both sides of the electric panel in such a way that it balances the load."*  No, they don't. Barring only using 240V loads (USA/Canada scheme) there will always be some imbalance, and that's OK.

Comment: @Ecnerwal This sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

### What matters is your *actual draw*, not the numbers on the breakers.

So for instance, if you have 5 circuits of bathroom, bedroom, laundry room, and kitchen... And then 5 circuits of Bitcoin miner that run at 15.9A 24x7... You don't want to put the miners on one leg and the household load on the other.  The 2 kitchen circuits are rarely used, for instance, so they don't balance the miners.

On the other hand, if you have a gaming rig circuit and an air conditioner circuit  to keep the room bearable, thatd be a pretty good balance since they'd  run together.

### It isn't left and right, unless it's PushMatic

Most modern panels arrange [like this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/110152/47125).